# A word for a position of a person who organizes and buy things for a camp

Tags: word-request

I was assigned a position in a camp to buy things that will be used (scissors, ropes, papers, balloons, glue, first aid, etc.), organize it into some space, and provide them when needed. It also have to clean up everything after all events. How to call this position?

Comment: I don't think there is one word that fits this very well, but *activities organizer* sounds reasonable.  The first thing that occurred to me was actually the word *quartermaster*, which is a military term for "a military officer responsible for providing quarters, rations, clothing, and other supplies."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this position is made up of two parts:

1. The purchase, storage, organization and dispensation of materials/equipment
2. The cleanup following an event

To some extent the best way to define a name for this role depends upon the other roles involved and their responsibilities, as there may be a generic term which could be used provided it doesn't overlap with the responsibilities of others (Event Coordinator for example).

Without any other information though I would suggest some combination of:

First word: Materials, Equipment, Inventory
Second word: Supervisor, Manager, Specialist

If it's relevant, you could prefix any combination of the above with `Event`, if your role is strictly limited to events and there are other individuals in the same organization who work outside of the scope of events.

Personally, I'd probably go for `(Event) Materials Manager`. While this doesn't explicitly deal with the second responsibility of cleaning up after event, the more significant responsibility seems to be the procurement, storage and distribution of the equipment/materials, with the cleanup being secondary. Plus, I suspect that a reasonable proportion of the stuff you're cleaning up is those materials (ropes, balloons, glue etc.) anyway.